# Wildcard for map redirect on Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm using map directive for some redirect.
I've to set some wildcard but it doesn't work:

```
/notizie~* /news;
```

I want that all urls like "/notizie/$string" should be redirect on "/news".

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the query params are important for your redirect:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
      ~^/notizie(?<suffix>.*)$ /news$suffix;
      default $request_uri;
    }
```

otherwise:

```
map $uri $redirect_uri {
      ~^/notizie(?<suffix>.*)$ /news$suffix;
      default $uri;
    }
```

Comment: This works:

~/notizie/(~*) /news;

But matches urls like "whatever/notizie/whatever", I've only to match urls that starts with "/notizie/"

I don't have to replicate suffix, every utl like /notizie/XXX should go simply to /news

Comment: In `~^/notizie` notice `^` which means "Start of string" so it will only match uri that *starts* with `/notizie`.  if you don't care about the suffix simply remove it like: `~^/notizie /news;`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a redirect with 301 HTTP code, you can use `location` with a regexp:

```
location ~* ^/notizie(.*)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/news$1;
}
```

`~*` - identifies a case-insensitive regexp

`$1` - refers to the captured match in the 1st brackets

`return` - stops the request processing end returns the given code and the url

`$host` - is a predefined variable, you may hardcode it, if you like

Comment: I've other redirects, so I'm using a map, in a separate file. Can I use this syntax also in map?

Comment: I haven't tested this with map, but regexps are suppported with maps http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html, so, why not?